# Node error when I deployed smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I get this error when I deployed smart contract to my private chain.

> Error: Node error: {"code":-32000,"message":"unknown account"}

This is my web3.js code.

```
 const bytecode = "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"
    var itemContract = new this.props.web3.eth.Contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getItem","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"itemId","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"id","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]);
 
itemContract.deploy({
  data: bytecode,
  arguments:[1]
})
.send({
  from: decryptEtherAccount.address,
  gas: 0,
  gasPrice: '0',
}).on('error', (error) => {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
}).on('transactionHash', (transactionHash) => {
    console.log("TxHash: ", transactionHash);
}).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
  console.log("Address: ", receipt.contractAddress)
}).then((newContractInstance) => {
    console.log(newContractInstance);   
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Could you give me any advise why I am getting this error, please?

Comment: Are you able to deploy using https://remix.ethereum.org or Truffle?

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin Thank you! But, in this case, I want to deploy contract without using truffle or remix.

Comment: can you `console.log` `decryptEtherAccount.address` and see if the account is correct. and why are you setting `gas` and `gasPrice` to `0`?

Comment: Firstly,I think you need some gas for contract deployment.
Secondly, are you using local blockchain (ganache) or whatever you are using - I don't think you are getting an active/proper address i.e. the 'from account'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using an address to send a transaction, make sure you have added it to your web3 wallet.

Guide: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding relevant info from the linked resource to the answer body itself. That way it doesn't lose its value when the link dies.